# Remove extension and add get value with traling slash

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

To do this :

**Original URL ->**  `localhost/viewprofile.php`

**ReWrite URL ->**  `localhost/viewprofile/`

I used this Code.

```
# Apache Rewrite Rules
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options +FollowSymLinks
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /

# Add trailing slash to url
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/|#(.*))$
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1/ [R=301,L]

# Remove .php-extension from url
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
  RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)/$ $1.php 

# End of Apache Rewrite Rules
 </IfModule>
```

Now to do this I used

**Original URL ->** `localhost/viewprofile.php?user_id = 1`

**ReWrite URL ->** `localhost/1/`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ viewprofile.php?user_id=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ viewprofile.php?user_id=$1
```

But Unfortunately I want to do this

**Original URL ->** `localhost/viewprofile.php?user_id = 1`

**ReWrite URL ->** `localhost/viewprofile/1/`

***and this***

**Original URL ->** `localhost/viewprofile.php?username=sean`

**ReWrite URL ->** `localhost/viewprofile/sean/`

I have those two `Original URLs` and i want to rewrite them as respective `ReWrite URL` respectively as given above.

Anyone any solutions?

Comment: Please briefly explain your question, so others can understand and answer accordingly.

Comment: `Original URL`  is what i have and `ReWrite URL` is what i want to achieve.   @PSN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can match on digits (only) for the first one and on alphanumeric for the other one (for instance)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /

  # Add trailing slash to url
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/|#(.*))$
  RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1/ [R=301,L]

  # Remove .php-extension from url
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f
  RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ $1.php [L]

  RewriteRule ^viewprofile/([0-9]+)/?$ viewprofile.php?user_id=$1 [L]
  RewriteRule ^viewprofile/([A-Za-z0-9]+)/?$ viewprofile.php?username=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Nope Dosen't works  when im trying `localhost/viewprofile/1/` its 404

Comment: Did you use exactly the code i provided you above ? Because there were some syntax errors and missing parts in your initial code. Also, where is located your htaccess ? In root folder ? Or in `viewprofile` folder if it's a physical folder ?

Comment: Yes i copied. Its in `root` folder And theres no such folder as `viewprofile` its just a `.php` file

Comment: Ok you're right, i didn't test it, my bad. I modified a `RewriteCond`, it's working now